# Swiper PlugIn internal fields get lost

Tags: git, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I just installed the [Swiper Plugin](https://github.com/camac/Swiper) on my `Domino Designer FP7` and after some tests (maybe) I found a bug.

Unfortunately internal fields like `$DesignerVersion` and `$$ScriptName` get lost if you switch between branches!

Here my test scenario:

1. Create a form (`form1.form`)
2. Make an initial commit to a `master` branch
3. Create an additional branch, e.g. `develop`
4. Do some changes on the `form1.form` in the `develop` branch
5. Commit this changes
6. Switch back to `master` branch

After this steps the internal fields (mentioned above) get lost :(

Comment: You should create an issue on the Github page for Swiper so that Cameron can answe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attributes and elements that Swiper decides to 'swipe' away is controlled by using an xslt file.

The default xslt file does indeed choose **DesignerVersion** and **$$ScriptName** to be swiped.

**DesignerVersion** is swiped by default, because this will cause a lot of merge conflicts when you upgrade domino designer, or if one of your colleagues decides to install a fixpack that you didn't all of a sudden every file will have a conflict again that needs to be resolved.

Although there may be the argument that import/export behaviour may be different for each version, I would be skeptical to hear that IBM have made any changes to DXL importing / exporting in the last few years.

Regarding $$ScriptName, to be honest I can't remember why I included that to be swiped but it must have been annoying me. It hasn't caused any problem for me, but then again I don't do a lot of classic NSF development so maybe that actually does cause a problem when doing that.

**Providing your own custom xslt filter**:

If you don't want these 'swiped' then you can provide a customised xslt file
Make a copy of the default file [org.openntf.swiper/src/org/openntf/swiper/action/DXLClean.xsl](https://github.com/camac/Swiper/blob/master/org.openntf.swiper/src/org/openntf/swiper/action/DXLClean.xsl)

Then comment or remove the entries related to Designer version (there are more than one)

```
<xsl:template match="//n:form/@replicaid"/>
<xsl:template match="//n:form/@version"/>
<!--<xsl:template match="//n:form/@designerversion"/>-->

<xsl:template match="//n:database/@replicaid"/>
<xsl:template match="//n:database/@version"/>
<!--<xsl:template match="//n:database/@designerversion"/>-->
.... and so on make sure you do all of them
```

Then comment out / remove the one for $$ScriptName

```
<!-- Ignore the DesignerVersion Item  and this random FileModDT one -->
<xsl:template match="//n:item[@name='$DesignerVersion']"/>
<!--<xsl:template match="//n:item[@name='$$ScriptName']"/>-->
<xsl:template match="//n:item[@name='$ScriptLib_error']"/>
<xsl:template match="//n:imageresource/n:item[@name='$FileModDT']"/>
<xsl:template match="//n:imageresource/n:item[@name='$EditFilePath']"/>
```

Save this as a .xsl file somewhere
Then in Designer go to File -> Preferences -> Swiper
Under 'Custom XSLT Filter' browse to the location of your file and click apply / ok.

These rules will then take affect the next time swiper runs when a file is exported from NSF to the ODP. So you may need to force a save of a file, or deliberately 'swipe' a file to see the new results.

Comment: Nicely written up Cameron.

Comment: @Cameron: First of all thanks for your plugin. A last question: Do you think there could be some negative side effects swipe out system fields like `$DesignerVersion` or `$$ScriptName`?

Comment: no problem Georg, here's an article that has some info on the fields. https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=29369AFF8E4874AB852574F30047C2E8#mobileViewer , for $$ScriptName i swiped it because it was a 'generated' field and not source code. it just means you might need to recompile all lotuscript after importing from ODP. one negative is that i think it does incorrectly swipe some javascript from old 'classic' web html notes forms. for designer version i haven't had a problem or had anyone report to me it caused a problem by swiping it. let me know if any more questions